# Little lisp challenge

Tags: lisp

I have a string like "2d 6:36", and I want to multiply that amount of hours by a constant.

**This means I want this to be calculated:**

```
(2*24 + 6 + 36/60) * constant
```

**or, in general**

```
(d*24 + h + m/60)
```

Any help?

Edit: I only have the *string* not, the d, h and m.

Comment: Are you sure you want that *100 in there?

Comment: Have you tried `(* constant (+ (* d 24) h (/ m 60)))`?  What are you looking for help with?  Writing LISP expressions? Parsing?

Comment: NeilForrester, you're right.
@RayToal, The parsing is the hard part, but now you've told me already how to write the formula, I needed that too.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not actually a site for Lisp challenges. It would be great if you could show some effort to actually solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse your string in something useful, for example a list of integers, you can use [cl-ppcre](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) for this:

```
(defun parse-day-and-time (string)
  "Get string like 3d 23:40 and return list (3 23 40)"
  (multiple-value-bind (str matches)
    (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "(\\d+)d ([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])" string)
    (declare (ignore str))
    (when (< (length matches) 3)
      (error "Wrong day and time string: ~A" string))
    (map 'list #'parse-integer matches)))
```

Then you can do yout calculation:

```
(defun mult-time (string-time coeff)
  (destructuring-bind (days hours minutes)
    (parse-day-and-time string-time)
    (* coeff (+ (* 24 days) hours (/ minutes 60)))))

CL-USER> (mult-time "2d 6:36" 300)
16380
```

Of cause if you want to do some more calculations with your time, may be it will be better to represent it as amount of seconds, do your calculation with it, then return it in any string you want.

Comment: Your `mult-time` doesn't use string-time but constant `"2d 6:36"`

Answer (score 1):

So I understand the data to be a human readable amount of time.. E.g. "2d 1:35" represent 2 days, 1 hour and 35 seconds or 595/12 hours. I'm tempted to let loose the spec for the string like this:

```
(defparameter *units* '(("w" . 168) ("d" . 24) (":" . 1)
                        ("h" . 1) ("m" . 1/60) ("s" . 1/3600)))
(defun str-to-hours (str &optional (acc 0))
  (or
   (cl-ppcre:register-groups-bind (num unit rest)
                                  ("(\\d+)\\s*(\\D{0,1})\\D*(.*)" str :sharedp t)
     (str-to-hours rest
                   (+ acc
                      (* (parse-integer num)
                         (or (cdr (assoc (string-downcase unit) 
                                         *units* 
                                         :test #'equal)) 
                              1/60)))))
   acc))

(str-to-hours  "2d 6:36")  ; ==> 273/5 ~54.6
(str-to-hours  "2D6H36M")  ; ==> 273/5 ~54.6
(str-to-hours  "2 weeks, 1 day, 3 hours, 7 minutes and 10 seconds") ; ==> 130723/360 ~363.11945

(* 10 (str-to-hours "2d6:36")) ; ==> 546
```